Transfer all tokens from contracts using wallet address
In my quest for mimicing an arbitrage I am attempting to build a replica of the transactions on Sepolia.
When I start a new test run I need to empty the DEXes so I built a script containing a series of cast calls.
The given addresses are deployed and verified on Sepolia with the exception of the WALLET_ADDRESS which is a Metamask address.
The idea is that the following commands are going to transfer all PIGFOX_TOKEN tokens from DEX2 to TRASH_CAN using the WALLET_ADDRESS to just pay for the transaction and sign it.
Environment Variables:9
DEX2=0x0b249989e0b4d7f6f6d8F96E7061a1C35A2B089F
TRASH_CAN=0x5657BEE1DcC98271e60095a8B12cEB0006930030
WALLET_ADDRESS=0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693
SEPOLIA_PUBLIC_NODE=https://ethereum-sepolia-rpc.publicnode.com
PIGFOX_TOKEN=0xAff8e5C19A00Bb6f65c47b787479bF803bF7eAb2

cast call 0xAff8e5C19A00Bb6f65c47b787479bF803bF7eAb2 'balanceOf(address)(uint256)' 0x0b249989e0b4d7f6f6d8F96E7061a1C35A2B089F --rpc-url https://ethereum-sepolia-rpc.publicnode.com
Raw balance of 0x0b249989e0b4d7f6f6d8F96E7061a1C35A2B089F: 3000000000000000000 [3e18]
Cleaned balance of 0x0b249989e0b4d7f6f6d8F96E7061a1C35A2B089F: 3000000000000000000
Balance in decimals: 14167099448608935641088

Balance in base units: 14167.099448608935641088
cast call 0xAff8e5C19A00Bb6f65c47b787479bF803bF7eAb2 'allowance(address,address)(uint256)' 0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693 0x0b249989e0b4d7f6f6d8F96E7061a1C35A2B089F --rpc-url https://ethereum-sepolia-rpc.publicnode.com
Allowance for 0x0b249989e0b4d7f6f6d8F96E7061a1C35A2B089F: 14167099448608935641088
Transferring tokens to 0x5657BEE1DcC98271e60095a8B12cEB0006930030
Attempting to transfer: 3000000000000000000 to 0x5657BEE1DcC98271e60095a8B12cEB0006930030
cast send 0xAff8e5C19A00Bb6f65c47b787479bF803bF7eAb2 'transferFrom(address,address,uint256)' 0x0b249989e0b4d7f6f6d8F96E7061a1C35A2B089F 0x5657BEE1DcC98271e60095a8B12cEB0006930030 3000000000000000000 --rpc-url https://ethereum-sepolia-rpc.publicnode.com --private-key xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --gas-limit 200000
cast call 0xAff8e5C19A00Bb6f65c47b787479bF803bF7eAb2 'balanceOf(address)(uint256)' 0x5657BEE1DcC98271e60095a8B12cEB0006930030 --rpc-url https://ethereum-sepolia-rpc.publicnode.com
New balance of 0x5657BEE1DcC98271e60095a8B12cEB0006930030: 0
Token transfer complete.


Looking at the last transactionHash it clearly shows
Fail with Custom Error 'ERC20InsufficientAllowance (spender=0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693, allowance=0, needed= ...'

Which is correct, the wallet 0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693, does not and should not have any tokens. The purpose of the wallet is to pay for gas and sign the transaction.
Any idea how to change the cast calls to transfer all PIGFOX_TOKEN tokens from DEX1 and DEX2 to TRASH_CAN using the WALLET_ADDRESS to just pay for the gas and sign the transaction?
Complete script here:
#!/bin/sh
#functions.sh
#set -x
set -e
clear
forge clean
. ./.env

hex2Int() {
    local hex_value="$1"

    # Clean the output by stripping '0x' and any extra whitespace
    hex_value=$(echo "$hex_value" | sed 's/^0x//' | tr -d '\n' | tr -d ' ')

    # Debugging: print hex_value to check its contents
    #echo "Debug: hex_value after cleaning is '$hex_value'"

    # Check if the value is not empty and valid for conversion
    if [ -z "$hex_value" ] || ! echo "$hex_value" | grep -qE '^[0-9a-fA-F]+$'; then
        echo "Error: Invalid hexadecimal value" >&2
        return 1
    fi

    # Convert the hex value to decimal using Python
    numerical_value=$(python3 -c "print(int('$hex_value', 16))")

    # Debugging: check the result of Python conversion
    #echo "Debug: numerical_value after Python conversion is '$numerical_value'"

    if [ -z "$numerical_value" ]; then
        echo "Error: Failed to convert hexadecimal to decimal" >&2
        return 1
    fi

    # Trim the result to remove any extra spaces (if any)
    trimmed_value=$(echo "$numerical_value" | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;s/[[:space:]]*$//')

    # Output the trimmed decimal value
    echo "$trimmed_value"
}

# Function to check if an address is a valid Ethereum address
is_valid_address() {
    if [[ "$1" =~ ^0x[a-fA-F0-9]{40}$ ]]; then
        return 0  # Valid address
    else
        return 1  # Invalid address
    fi
}

# Function to check if a value is greater than zero
is_greater_than_zero() {
  if [[ $(echo "$1 > 0" | bc) -eq 1 ]]; then
    return 0  # Greater than zero
  else
    return 1  # Not greater than zero
  fi
}

#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -x
clear
. ./.env
. ./functions.sh  # Source the external functions

# Debugging: Print the environment variables
echo "Environment Variables:"
echo "DEX1=$DEX1"
echo "DEX2=$DEX2"
echo "TRASH_CAN=$TRASH_CAN"
echo "WALLET_ADDRESS=$WALLET_ADDRESS"
echo "SEPOLIA_PUBLIC_NODE=$SEPOLIA_PUBLIC_NODE"
echo "PIGFOX_TOKEN=$PIGFOX_TOKEN"

# Check if the provided addresses are valid
for address in "$DEX1" "$DEX2" "$TRASH_CAN"; do
    if ! is_valid_address "$address"; then
        echo "Invalid Ethereum address: $address"
        exit 1
    fi
done

# Empty DEX
echo "-------------------------DEX1-------------------------"
# Fetch the balance of $DEX1 in $PIGFOX_TOKEN (in base units)
BALANCE_RAW=$(cast call "$PIGFOX_TOKEN" "balanceOf(address)(uint256)" "$DEX1" --rpc-url "$SEPOLIA_PUBLIC_NODE")

# Debugging: Print the raw balance to see the format
echo "Raw balance of $DEX1: $BALANCE_RAW"

# Clean up the balance raw result by removing unwanted characters
BALANCE_RAW_CLEAN=$(echo "$BALANCE_RAW" | sed 's/\[.*//g' | sed 's/\]//g' | tr -d '\n' | tr -d ' ')

# Ensure the balance is in hex format and does not contain scientific notation
if [[ "$BALANCE_RAW_CLEAN" =~ "e" ]]; then
    echo "Balance in scientific notation detected. Converting to raw format."
    BALANCE_RAW_CLEAN=$(printf "%.0f" "$BALANCE_RAW_CLEAN")
fi

echo "Cleaned balance of $DEX1: $BALANCE_RAW_CLEAN"

# Convert the balance from hex to decimal using hex2Int
BALANCE_DECIMAL=$(hex2Int "$BALANCE_RAW_CLEAN")

# Assuming the token has 18 decimals (standard ERC20 token decimals)
DECIMALS=18

# Convert the raw balance to human-readable format
BALANCE_BASE_UNIT=$(echo "scale=$DECIMALS; $BALANCE_DECIMAL / (10 ^ $DECIMALS)" | bc)

echo "Balance in decimals: $BALANCE_DECIMAL"
echo "Balance in base units: $BALANCE_BASE_UNIT"

# Check allowance for $DEX1 to ensure it has permission to transfer the tokens
ALLOWANCE_RAW=$(cast call "$PIGFOX_TOKEN" "allowance(address,address)(uint256)" "$WALLET_ADDRESS" "$DEX1" --rpc-url "$SEPOLIA_PUBLIC_NODE")
ALLOWANCE_RAW_HEX=$(echo "$ALLOWANCE_RAW" | awk '{print $1}')
ALLOWANCE_DECIMAL=$(hex2Int "$ALLOWANCE_RAW_HEX")

echo "Allowance for $DEX1: $ALLOWANCE_DECIMAL"

# Ensure sufficient allowance for $DEX1
ALLOWANCE_LESS_THAN_BALANCE=$(echo "$ALLOWANCE_DECIMAL < $BALANCE_DECIMAL" | bc)

if [ "$ALLOWANCE_LESS_THAN_BALANCE" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Insufficient allowance, approving full balance for $DEX1"
    cast send "$PIGFOX_TOKEN" "approve(address,uint256)" "$DEX1" "$BALANCE_RAW_CLEAN" --rpc-url "$SEPOLIA_PUBLIC_NODE" --private-key "$PRIVATE_KEY"
else
    echo "Sufficient allowance for $DEX1"
fi

# Check if balance is greater than zero before transferring
if ! is_greater_than_zero "$BALANCE_DECIMAL"; then
    echo "Balance is zero or invalid. Aborting transfer."
    exit 1
fi

# Transfer tokens from DEX1 to TRASH_CAN
echo "Transferring tokens to $TRASH_CAN"
echo "Attempting to transfer: $BALANCE_RAW_CLEAN to $TRASH_CAN"
TRANSFER_RESULT=$(cast send "$PIGFOX_TOKEN" \
    "transferFrom(address,address,uint256)" \
    "$DEX1" \
    "$TRASH_CAN" \
    "$BALANCE_RAW_CLEAN" \
    --rpc-url "$SEPOLIA_PUBLIC_NODE" \
    --private-key "$PRIVATE_KEY" \
    --gas-limit 200000)  # Increased gas limit

# Check for errors in the transfer result
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error during transfer. Transaction failed with revert."
    exit 1
fi

# Check new balance of $TRASH_CAN
TRANSFER_RESULT=$(cast call "$PIGFOX_TOKEN" "balanceOf(address)(uint256)" "$TRASH_CAN" --rpc-url "$SEPOLIA_PUBLIC_NODE")
TRANSFER_RAW_HEX=$(echo "$TRANSFER_RESULT" | awk '{print $1}')
TRANSFER_DECIMAL=$(hex2Int "$TRANSFER_RAW_HEX")
echo "New balance of $TRASH_CAN: $TRANSFER_DECIMAL"

echo "-------------------------DEX2-------------------------"
# Fetch the balance of $DEX2 in $PIGFOX_TOKEN (in base units)
BALANCE_RAW=$(cast call "$PIGFOX_TOKEN" "balanceOf(address)(uint256)" "$DEX2" --rpc-url "$SEPOLIA_PUBLIC_NODE")

# Debugging: Print the raw balance to see the format
echo "Raw balance of $DEX2: $BALANCE_RAW"

# Clean up the balance raw result by removing unwanted characters
BALANCE_RAW_CLEAN=$(echo "$BALANCE_RAW" | sed 's/\[.*//g' | sed 's/\]//g' | tr -d '\n' | tr -d ' ')

# Ensure the balance is in hex format and does not contain scientific notation
if [[ "$BALANCE_RAW_CLEAN" =~ "e" ]]; then
    echo "Balance in scientific notation detected. Converting to raw format."
    BALANCE_RAW_CLEAN=$(printf "%.0f" "$BALANCE_RAW_CLEAN")
fi

echo "Cleaned balance of $DEX2: $BALANCE_RAW_CLEAN"

# Convert the balance from hex to decimal using hex2Int
BALANCE_DECIMAL=$(hex2Int "$BALANCE_RAW_CLEAN")

# Assuming the token has 18 decimals (standard ERC20 token decimals)
DECIMALS=18

# Convert the raw balance to human-readable format
BALANCE_BASE_UNIT=$(echo "scale=$DECIMALS; $BALANCE_DECIMAL / (10 ^ $DECIMALS)" | bc)

echo "Balance in decimals: $BALANCE_DECIMAL"
echo "Balance in base units: $BALANCE_BASE_UNIT"

# Check allowance for $DEX2 to ensure it has permission to transfer the tokens
ALLOWANCE_RAW=$(cast call "$PIGFOX_TOKEN" "allowance(address,address)(uint256)" "$WALLET_ADDRESS" "$DEX2" --rpc-url "$SEPOLIA_PUBLIC_NODE")
ALLOWANCE_RAW_HEX=$(echo "$ALLOWANCE_RAW" | awk '{print $1}')
ALLOWANCE_DECIMAL=$(hex2Int "$ALLOWANCE_RAW_HEX")

echo "Allowance for $DEX2: $ALLOWANCE_DECIMAL"

# Ensure sufficient allowance for $DEX2
ALLOWANCE_LESS_THAN_BALANCE=$(echo "$ALLOWANCE_DECIMAL < $BALANCE_DECIMAL" | bc)

if [ "$ALLOWANCE_LESS_THAN_BALANCE" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Insufficient allowance, approving full balance for $DEX2"
    cast send "$PIGFOX_TOKEN" "approve(address,uint256)" "$DEX2" "$BALANCE_RAW_CLEAN" --rpc-url "$SEPOLIA_PUBLIC_NODE" --private-key "$PRIVATE_KEY"
else
    echo "Sufficient allowance for $DEX2"
fi

# Check if balance is greater than zero before transferring
if ! is_greater_than_zero "$BALANCE_DECIMAL"; then
    echo "Balance is zero or invalid. Aborting transfer."
    exit 1
fi

# Transfer tokens from DEX1 to TRASH_CAN
echo "Transferring tokens to $TRASH_CAN"
echo "Attempting to transfer: $BALANCE_RAW_CLEAN to $TRASH_CAN"
TRANSFER_RESULT=$(cast send "$PIGFOX_TOKEN" \
    "transferFrom(address,address,uint256)" \
    "$DEX2" \
    "$TRASH_CAN" \
    "$BALANCE_RAW_CLEAN" \
    --rpc-url "$SEPOLIA_PUBLIC_NODE" \
    --private-key "$PRIVATE_KEY" \
    --gas-limit 200000)  # Increased gas limit

# Check for errors in the transfer result
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error during transfer. Transaction failed with revert."
    exit 1
fi

# Check new balance of $TRASH_CAN
TRANSFER_RESULT=$(cast call "$PIGFOX_TOKEN" "balanceOf(address)(uint256)" "$TRASH_CAN" --rpc-url "$SEPOLIA_PUBLIC_NODE")
TRANSFER_RAW_HEX=$(echo "$TRANSFER_RESULT" | awk '{print $1}')
TRANSFER_DECIMAL=$(hex2Int "$TRANSFER_RAW_HEX")
echo "New balance of $TRASH_CAN: $TRANSFER_DECIMAL"

echo "Token transfer complete."



You mean you want some other wallet to sign and pay for the gas, while another is actually the sender? That's not really possible before we have real account abstraction wallets.

@LauriPeltonen No it is the same wallet that deployed all the contracts, signed every previous transaction.
The same wallet for everything.

Ok then I'm afraid I don't understand the original issue

For transferring the PIGFOX_TOKEN (or basically any ERC20 token) from your DEX2 contract (or any contract having that particular token balance), you need to approve the spending of that token from within the contract.
Since, the DEX2 contract is the owner of the token and the wallet address with which you're calling the transferFrom function is the spender, therefore the transaction is getting failed with the ERC20InsufficientAllowance error.
So, in your DEX2 contract, you can add a function like:
function approveTokenTransfer(address token, address spender, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
    IERC20(token).approve(spender, amount);
}

Then, once you deploy your DEX2 (say NEW_DEX2) containing the approveTokenTransfer function, you can call that function by passing the token address (i.e, 0xAff8e5C19A00Bb6f65c47b787479bF803bF7eAb2), your wallet address or the spender (i.e., 0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693) and the amount (i.e., 3000000000000000000), like:
cast send NEW_DEX2 'approveTokenTransfer(address,address,uint256)' 0xAff8e5C19A00Bb6f65c47b787479bF803bF7eAb2 0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693 3000000000000000000 --rpc-url https://ethereum-sepolia-rpc.publicnode.com --private-key xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Then, after that when you call the transferFrom function, the transaction would be successful.

Since, your wallet address is also the owner of the DEX2 contract, so to transfer the tokens to the TRASH_CAN contract, you can also call the withdrawTokens function, like:
cast send 0x0b249989e0b4d7f6f6d8F96E7061a1C35A2B089F 'withdrawTokens(address,address,uint256)' 0xAff8e5C19A00Bb6f65c47b787479bF803bF7eAb2 0x5657BEE1DcC98271e60095a8B12cEB0006930030 3000000000000000000 --rpc-url https://ethereum-sepolia-rpc.publicnode.com --private-key xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

